# jQuery: hide/ show + change text clicking the same class

Tags: jquery

I have a group of words that on click should show and hide elements. In addition, I need to change that first group of words. So if it gets clicked, it shows the container with content + gets changed to hide. In alternative, when it is clicked again, it should hide the content and become 'show' again.

```
<div class="hide-show-button">Click Here to <span id="hide-show-changed">Show</span></div>
<div class="hide-show">
.... content
</div>

    <script>
    $('.hide-show').hide();

    $('.hide-show-button').click(function(){
    $('.hide-show').show();
    $('#hide-show-changed').text('Hide');
    }, function() {
    $('.hide-show').hide();
    $('#hide-show-changed').text('Show');
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a counter to toggle between hide and show.

```
var click = 0;
$('.hide-show-button').click(function() {
     if(click == 1)
     {
        $(this).text('show');
        $('.hide-show').hide();
        click--;
     }
     else
     {
        $(this).text('hide');
        $('.hide-show').show();
        click++;
     }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.text()` method's callback function and `this` keyword which refers to the clicked element.

```
<div class="hide-show-button">
       Click Here to <span class="hide-show-changed">Show</span>
</div>
<div class="hide-show">
.... content
</div>
```

```
$('.hide-show-button').on('click', function(){
   var fn;
   $('span', this).text(function(_, text) {
       fn = text.toLowerCase();
       return text === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
   }).parent().next()[fn]();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KzwXQ/

As [@Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287470/joe) suggests you can also use `.toggle()` method:

```
$('.hide-show-button').on('click', function () {
    $('span', this).text(function (_, currentText) {
        return currentText === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    }).parent().next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, if the element is only hidden/shown by this piece of code then you could use `toggle()` to make it even smaller: http://jsfiddle.net/KzwXQ/1/